# WordPress Customizer JavaScript Hide Page Title

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a checkbox control in my WordPress Customizer to display a page title if checked and hide it if unchecked, but the javascript isn't working:

```
wp.customize( 'display_page_title', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to ) {
        if ( true === to ) {
            $( '#page-title' ).removeClass( 'hidden' );
        } else {
            $( '#page-title' ).addClass( 'hidden' );
        }
    });
});
```

P.S. 'hidden' is a bootstrap class to hide elements

Comment: Yes I have. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
wp.customize( 'display_page_title', function( value ) {
value.bind( function( to ) {
    if ( true !== to ) {
        $( '#page-title' ).addClass( 'hidden' );
    } 
});
```

});